# Unable to store facebook profile pic while login with facebook

Tags: php

I am using following code for storing image in my website dir

```
 $fb_id=1120381158031234;//eg
 $image = file_get_contents($userArray['picture']['data']['url']);
 file_put_contents('../images/profiles/fb_id'.$fb_id.'.gif', $image);
```

but getting this error

Warning: file_put_contents(../images/profiles/fb_id_1120381158031234.gif): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/facebook.php on line 48

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/facebook.php:48) in /XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/login-facebook.php on line 38

Comment: As the error message is saying. You are trying to store it in a folder that doesn't exists

Comment: but i have that folder

Comment: The error message say it doesn't exists.

Comment: all code is correct am unable to find whats incorrect

Comment: I would bet that the code is wrong.

Comment: is there mistake in fb_id'.$fb_id.'.gif

Comment: No because the error message say that the path becomes "../images/profiles/fb_id_1120381158031234.gif"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem:

Your code is running inside facebook.php. Your code tries to reach the folder `images` as a sibling of the folder facebook.php is in. It fails either when searching for that folder or when searching for the `profiles` subfolder. Note, that one of these does not exist at the point your code is searching for it or the OS user executing the PHP code does not have write privileges on one of those folders.

Test by running the following code:

```
echo getcwd();
```

just before your call to `file_get_contents`. You will see then where the folders are searched for.

As about the second problem, [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) should make things clear about it.

Comment: @sunilwananje, what did echo getcwd(); print on your browser screen?

Comment: echo getcwd(); getting this /home3/ecom/public_html

Comment: Do you have an images folder inside public_html and a profiles folder inside the images folder?

Comment: Then it is an issue with the privilege to one of those folders.

Comment: are you talking about permission?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the user which runs the PHP code.  That user might have no write privilege on one of those folders.

Comment: @sunilwananje, you are welcome, I was happy to help.

Comment: there is a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory